# Why is mongo aggregation not reactive in meteor

Tags: meteor

Meteor newb here. I'm perplexed by the reactivity of Meteor. I can update a collection from a Mongo console, and it will update the UI instantly. But not with mongo aggregate?

I'm using meteorhacks:aggregate to get mongo's aggregate() loaded in meteor.

The aggregation works great. I can see the data update instantly in a mongo console. However if I expose it to the UI, there is no update, even on a client refresh.

db.collection:

```
{a:1,b:2}
{a:1,b:2}
```

The code:

```
inputCollection = new Meteor.Collection('input_collection')
outputCollection = new Meteor.Collection('output_collection')

Meteor.methods({
    pleaseAggregate: function() {
      inputCollection.aggregate([{
        $group : {
            _id : "$a",
            count: { $sum: 1} //should return 2 with the sample data above
        }
      },
      {$out : "output_collection"}
       ]);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<p>Aggregates: {{agg.count}}</p>
```

Client.js

```
Template.debug.helpers({
 agg: function() {
    return outputCollection.find().fetch()[0]
  }
});
```

BTW it is being published, I have 'insecure' installed.

I'm missing something obvious to meteor I guess. What is it?

Comment: Method calls are not reactive whether or not you are using aggregations. I'm unclear what `AggCollection` is... are you expecting that's where the aggregated results should go? If so, I think we need to erase the chalkboard and start over.

Comment: @DavidWeldon are you sure? I have other method calls "inputCollection.remove({})" which will always update the UI reactively. I renamed some vars for clarity.

Comment: Let me clarify - the __result__ of a method call is not reactive. The side effects certainly could be. So if I call a method that returns a document, that call isn't reactive. If I call a method that inserts a document, the consequence of that action (a new document) could cause a reactive update on the client. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's very difficult to compute a live aggregation query, that's why.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks David. If you look at my code, I am outputting to a collection in mongo  {$out : "output_collection"} . This concludes successfully, and i can see the results in the mongo console. However I can see the data appear in the UI *only*  after a full meteor restart. So why is it that after inserting a mongo document in aggregate, is different from inserting normally?

Comment: just set this up myself,  and yeah, the insert into the output collection isn't seen by Meteor

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'm glad someone else could reproduce. Where would you guess the point of failure is? Mongo? Meteor Server? Package?

Comment: Meteor monitors the oplog of Mongo to reactively update data, I'm guessing the result of the aggregation does something in the oplog that Meteor doesn't recognize so doesn't know the collections updated

Comment: @KeithNicholas ( saw your post in the meteor forum as well). Meteor oplog is optional as I understand. I'm still producing the error without oplog enabled. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

So far everything indicates a bug up to meteor 1.1.0.2 . 
Using the $out from Mongo `aggregate` seems to be the issue server-side.

For anyone seeking a work-around it is possible to get a reactive update like so:

```
results = Collection.aggregate([{
        $group : {
            _id : "$a",
            count: { $sum: 1} //should return 2 with the sample data above
        }
   }]);

OtherCollection.insert(results);
```

Comment: This may not be what you want. As I understand it, using your original method with "$out", all the data stays inside MongoDB and things stay fast.

Using this method, when you use "results =", everything gets pulled into your web process over (potentially) a network connection. Then the insert will push it all back (also, with stock Meteor I think you need to loop over results).

So this is momentarily using potentially a lot of memory on the web server, since the whole of "results" will be in RAM. It's also potentially using bandwidth between the Mongo and web server.

Answer (score 0):

Was brought here by the search engine, don't know if will be helpful, but I've also experienced the non-reactive aggregations in Meteor. I used [a library for reactive publications](https://github.com/JcBernack/meteor-reactive-aggregate).